# batch rename directories from "NOTE" to "NOTES"

Tags: batch-rename

I would like to rename directories whose name contains the word "NOTE", but not "NOTES", to "NOTES". I first experiment with the `echo` command.

```
for /f "tokens=1-7"  %%i in ('dir d:\mydirectory /s /b /ad ^|find "NOTE" ^|find "NOTES" /v') do @echo %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%oS
```

Because directory names have different spaces in them, the above command may leave spaces between "NOTE" and S. Anyway to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a burl.  If it echo's the right rename command then remove the `echo` and the `pause` to activate it.  It's untested.  Paths containing `!` and `%` characters will cause an issue.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
  set "f=%%~nxa"
     if not "!f:NOTE=!"=="%%~nxa" (
        if "!f:NOTES=!"=="%%~nxa" (
           echo ren "%%a" "!f:NOTE=NOTES!"
           pause
        )
     )
)
```